# Training ML classifier for a group of users

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a Machine Learning project that given the reactions of a group of users on a collection of online articles (displayed by means of like/dislike) I need to make a decision for a newly arrived article.

The task dictates that given each individual's reaction to be able to predict whether the newly arrived article should be considered as to be recommended to the community as a whole.

I have been wondering how am I supposed to incorporate each user's feedback to dictate whether this would be an interesting article to recommend.

Bearing in mind that within users' reactions there would be users that like and dislike the same article is there a way to incorporate all this information and reach a conclusion about the article?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to determine what's "interesting." I think reddit has a pretty good model to look at in considering different options. They have different categories, like "hot", or "controversial", etc.

So a couple options depending on what you/your professor want:

- Take the net number of likes (like = +1, dislike = -1)
- Take just the number of likes
- Take the total number of ratings (who's read it at all)
- Take the ones with the highest percentage of likes vs. dislikes
- Some combination of these things

Etc.

So there are a lot of different things you could try. Maybe try a few and see which produce results most like what you want?

In terms of how to predict whether a *new* article compares to the articles you already have information about, that's a much broader question, but I don't think that's what you're asking, and it seems like that's what the Machine Learning project is about.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the recommending an article in this way is good, but if this is what your requirement then let me suggest you an approach.

**Approach:**
First, for every article give a lable(like/dislike) based on the number of likes & dislikes. Now you have set of articles with like/dislike lables. Based on this data you need to identify whether a new article's lable is like/dislike. This comes under simple linear classification problem, which can be solved by using any of the open source ml frameworks.

let us say, we have
- n number of users in the Group
- m number of articles

### sample data

user1 article1 like
user1 article2 dislike
user2 article3 dislike
....
usern articlem like

**Implementation**:

```
for each article    
    count the number of likes    
    count the nubmer of dislikes    
    if no. of likes > no. of dislikes, 
       lable = like    
    else  
       lable = dislike
```

Give this input(articles with lables) to naive bayes(or any) classifier to build a model.
Use this model to classify, the new article.

**Output**: like/dislike, if you get like recommend the article.

**Known Issues**:
1. What is half of the users likes & other half dislikes the article, Will you consider it as a like or dislike?
2. What is 11 users dislike & 10 users like, is it Okay to consider this as dislike?

Such Questions should be answered by yourself or your client as a part of requirement clarification.